# Form validation onblur() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, onblur

I have this javascript code (the function SHA-1 is located in an external file):

```
    window.onload = validatePass;

    function validatePass() {
        var el = document.getElementById("oriPass");

        var user_pass = el.value;
        var hashed_pass = SHA1(user_pass);

        var span = document.createElement("span");
        el.parentNode.appendChild(span); 

        el.onblur = function doSomething() {
            if(user_pass == null || user_pass == "") {
                span.setAttribute('class','required');
                span.innerHTML="this is a required field";
            }
            else {
                if(hashed_pass != '7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b') {
                    span.setAttribute('class','required');
                    span.innerHTML="wrong password";
                }
                else {
                    span.setAttribute('class','required_ok');
                        span.innerHTML="valid password";    
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

and this in html:

```
    <form name="form" method="post" action="change_pass.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">write your password:<span class="required">&#42;</span></div>
        <div class="col2">
            <input type="password" name="original_pass" id="oriPass" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

For some reason, every time I test it I get the same output: "valid password", no matter if the field is empty, valid or invalid.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this blowing up the same across all browsers? How are you 'blurring' away? With a mouse-click or tabbing?

Comment: its actually outputs different things in different browsers but the output will not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the `var user_pass...`  and `var hashed_pass...` code inside the onblur function. Now the are assigned only onload and will never change. Also it might be better to use onchange instead of onblur.

```
window.onload = validatePass;

function validatePass() {
    var el = document.getElementById("oriPass");


    var span = document.createElement("span");
    el.parentNode.appendChild(span); 

    el.onchange = function doSomething() {
        var user_pass = el.value;
        var hashed_pass = SHA1(user_pass);
        if(user_pass == null || user_pass == "") {
            span.setAttribute('class','required');
            span.innerHTML="this is a required field";
        }
        else {
            if(hashed_pass != '7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b') {
                span.setAttribute('class','required');
                span.innerHTML="wrong password";
            }
            else {
                span.setAttribute('class','required_ok');
                    span.innerHTML="valid password";    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the variable for password only on load.  It never changes after that.  You need to set it inside the onblur function.